Directory PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied - Python
I'm trying to run a python program on PyCharm. When I try to access a directory I tranferred from Roboflow that has a trained model for image detection it gives

PermissionError:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'F:\ProjetosPython\pythonProject\license_plate_detector_model.pt'

The program uses yolov8, I've tried using VSCode it gives the exact same error
I also tried on a different computer, exact same problem
This is how I call the directory
 I updated it to the full path just to make sure
I have changed the permissions on pretty much every single file/directory in the project here

This is the full project directory
 ls
I've also tried changing the python interpreter, reinstalling PyCharm, reinstalling Python in general, changing the default windows python.
The program does run with no issue once I remove the access to the directory... so I'm thinking it's probably something to do with a specific roboflow file?

Either you are not running program as administrator or the file is being used in another program

@LuisSouto, are you running from WSL, docker or some other way? Please provide more details about your environment.
